# SQL: Querying between multiple sets of values?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Struggling to figure this out, maybe because I'm not sure how to search it as a question.

I have a table with name, start_time and end_time columns. I want to calculate the sum of end_time - start_time for all entries that occurred between two dates, ie. start_time is after specified start, end_time is before specified end. I know how to do this for one set:

```
    SELECT name, SUM(end_time-start_time) AS time FROM table WHERE start_time >= ? AND end_time <= ?, (start, end)
```

I have four sets of start and ends though, and I'd ideally like to do them all the one query so I don't have to be appending things in Python. So output of this form:

```
    name, sum(end_time-start_time) between start1 and end1, sum(end_time-start_time) between start2 and end2...ETC
```

I don't really understand how the multiple starts and ends can fit into the query. Can it be done?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite you can get the difference of 2 datetimes in seconds with:

```
strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time)
```

because the function:

```
strftime('%s', some_datetime_column)
```

returns the number of seconds since `1970-01-01`.

In your case you can use conditional aggregation for all 4 sets of start and end dates like this:

```
select name,
       sum(case when start_time >= ? AND end_time <= ? then strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time) else 0 end) total1,
       sum(case when start_time >= ? AND end_time <= ? then strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time) else 0 end) total2,
       sum(case when start_time >= ? AND end_time <= ? then strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time) else 0 end) total3,
       sum(case when start_time >= ? AND end_time <= ? then strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time) else 0 end) total4
from tablename
group by name
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks